# Admin Grid Mass Action delete not working for custom module for Magento 2.2.4

Tags: magento2.2.4, massaction, custom-admin-grid

I am new to Magento and building a custom module. I need to show the admin grid to list data and it’s working fine. Also trying to add mass delete option but that’s not working. Getting below error when I try to delete.

```
{"0":"Invalid method Magento\\Framework\\View\\Element\\UiComponent\\DataProvider\\Document::delete","1":"#0
```

Can you please help

Here is my controller

```
    <?php


namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Quote;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter;
use Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest\CollectionFactory;


class MassDelete extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * Mass action Filter
     *
     * @var \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter
     */
    protected $_filter;

    /**
     * Collection Factory
     *
     * @var Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest\CollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_collectionFactory;




    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        Filter  $filter,
        CollectionFactory   $collectionFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->_filter  =   $filter;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
      $collection   =   $this->_filter->getCollection($this->_collectionFactory->create());
      $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
      foreach ($collection as $item){
          $item->delete();
      }

      $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', $collectionSize));
      $resultRedirect   =   $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
      $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
      return $resultRedirect;
    }

}
```

And here is my Admin ui listing xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">quoterequest_quote_list.quoterequest_quote_list_data_source</item>
            <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">quoterequest_quote_list.quoterequest_quote_list_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">spinner_columns</item>
        <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="add" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Add New Quote</item>
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
                <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/new</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <dataSource name="quoterequest_quote_list_data_source">
        <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
            <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider</argument>
            <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">quoterequest_quote_list_data_source</argument>
            <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                    <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </argument>
    </dataSource>

    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks"/>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <exportButton name="export_button"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <filterSearch name="fulltext"/>
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="quoterequest/quote/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete item</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>

    <columns name="spinner_columns">
        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="resizeEnabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="resizeDefaultWidth" xsi:type="string">55</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>
        <column name="id">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Name</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="email">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Email</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

    </columns>
</listing>
```

Here is my di.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <virtualType name="George\QuoteRequest\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">george_quoterequest</argument>
            <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">George\QuoteRequest\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="quoterequest_quote_list_data_source" xsi:type="string">George\QuoteRequest\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest\Collection</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

</config>
```

Comment: share the code of your di.xml file where you create virtual type for this.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya- Added the di.xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolve this issue and updated my di.xml file

```
    <virtualType name="Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest\**Grid**\Collection"

<item name="quoterequest_quote_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\QuoteRequest\**Grid**\Collection</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar component, the only difference I see is in the provider of the data to be used in the MassAction tag. This is the portion of my xml file, that differs from your:

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">listing.listing.columns.ids</item>
            <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <action name="delete">
```

Comment: I try that as well but still the same issue.

Comment: Have a look at this tutorial: https://aionhill.com/magento-2-module-development-part-2. He's creating a MassDelete page that works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your mass listing code into xml file like this.

```
<massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">

<item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">quoterequest_quote_list.quoterequest_quote_list.quoterequest_quote_list_columns.ids</item>
              <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/tree-massactions</item>
              <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <action name="delete">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="quoterequest/quote/massDelete"/>
                        <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete item</item>
                            <item name="message" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you wan't to delete selected items?</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
```

Comment: I try what you said but still showing same error